# Symfony -Return json output of Command Class from Controller

Tags: php, api, symfony, command, symfony4

In my Symfony project I have created a Command class to delete specific user.

I injected required parameter "email" in the Command class constructor.

I have never tried to implement command in the Controller so I have problem there.

I want to trigger the API call in the Controller which will return desired json output if command is successful.

How can I accomplish that?

My Command class:

```
protected static $defaultName = 'user:delete';

$entityManager;
private $userService;
private $email;

public function __construct(string $email = null, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, KeycloakApi $keycloakApi)
{
    parent::__construct($email);

    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    $this->userService = $userService;
}

protected function configure()
{
    $this
        ->setDescription('Deletion of selected user.')
        ->addArgument('email', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'User email');
}

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $user = $this->userService->getUserByEmail($this->email);
    if (empty($user)) {
        throw new Exception('USER_DOESNT_EXIST');
    }

    $this->userService->deleteUser($user['id']);
    $output->writeln('Done!');
}
```

And my try in controller to get what I want:

```
/**
 * @Route("/delete/test", name="delete_test")
 */
public function testDelete(): JsonResponse
{

    $application = new Application($this->kernel);
    $application->setAutoExit(false);

    $input = new ArrayInput(array("user:delete"));
    $output = new BufferedOutput();
    // Run the command
    $retval = $application->run($input, $output);

    dump($retval);die;
}
```

And the main question is how to pass email parameter in command that is needed to be provided for this endpoint?

Comment: why don't you call `userService` directly from your controller ? It a practice to avoid to call a command in a controller because you're mixing cli and web contecxt. Also it hurt performances for no gain

Comment: There will be three types of delete and this is the first one. So one api call will handle all three at once.. All three will be inputed in command classes. @Mcsky

Comment: This is a very bad idea. If you want to isolate logic for reuse, move it to a another layer that both the HTTP controller and the console command use.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments said, you shouldn't call a command from a controller, both are a different entry point of your application. Controller are used to access from the web and Command to be executed from a cli.

You should put your domain logic in neither of those files.

Here's an example which is possible :

Controller :

```
/**
 * @Route("/delete/{email}", name="delete")
 */
public function delete(string $email, DeleteUserHandler $handler): JsonResponse
{
    $handler->handle($email);

    return new JsonReponse(null, 204);
}
```

DeleteUserHandler :

```
...
public function handle(string $email): void
{
    $user = $this->userService->getUserByEmail($this->email);
    if (empty($user)) {
        throw new Exception('USER_DOESNT_EXIST');
    }

    $this->userService->deleteUser($user['id']);
}
```

I kept a bit of you code but IMO you don't even need to find before the delete (just maybe add a security to avoid anyone to delete anyone)

With this kind of code you can reuse the "DeleteUserHandler" in a command (or wherever) if you need it and the code which really delete a user isn't coupled with the entry point anymore